# Saving data in associated table

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am unable to save data in related tables

I have tables

```
ProductsTable
ProductsPricesTable
```

in `ProductsTable` table I have declared a relation like

```
public function initialize( array $config ) {
  parent::initialize($config);
  ...
  $this->hasMany('ProductsPrices');
}
```

and in ProductsController's add action I have something like

```
    if( $this->request->is('post') ) {

      $this->Products->patchEntity( $entity, $this->request->data, [
        'associated' => ['ProductsPrices']
      ]);

      if( $this->Products->save( $entity ) ) {
        ....
        ....
      }
   }
```

and the `request->data` looks like

```
[
    'category_id' => '68',
    'code' => '20',
    'name' => 'Tagliatelle Bolognese',
    'description' => 'mit Fleischsauce ',
    'order' => '20',
    'active' => '1',
    'offered' => '0',
    'productsprices' => [
        (int) 0 => [
            'size_id' => '80',
            'price' => '7'
        ]
    ]
]
```

it saves only product in `prodcts` table, but in products_prices table is nothing saved. whose structure looks like

```
id | product_id | size_id | price | created | modified
```

Any idea?

Comment: try ```$entity = $this->Products->patchEntity(....```

Comment: I think your data may need to have a key of `products_prices`, not `productsprices`.